# Splitting column with delimiter into multiple columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, splitting, column

In Excel we have option called 'Text to columns' to split the data in a column.

Is there any option available in QGIS?

There is an option which splits data from left or right in QGIS but I want entire data to be split.

[image]

Comment: Are there always three values to split in COLUMN?

Comment: @BERA Not three there are more some times

Comment: Excel has a lot of columns to work with, your data does not, excel can have numbers, letters, formulas, OLE objects etc. in a column, your data can not, so it's obviously easier in Excel. Multiple field calcs with the python string.split() function using the first column *.split('-')[index]* where *index* is the number identifier of the column you have got would work or alternately you could do your text-to-columns in excel and join that table to your data using the single value you do have.

Comment: you can use the processing tool "refactor fields", create new fields and for each one, paste the expression and adapt it a little : `string_to_array("your_origin_column", '-')[0]` (0 for the first new column, 1 for the second new column, 2 for ...). You can easily create a QGIS processing model with 6 new columns and if your data has only 3 data, the last 3 columns will be filled with a `NULL` value.

Comment: @J.Monticolo nice approach which I will also consider if I had few records in a string. The problem is what if you have many records in one string, e.g. *1-2-3-4-5-...-100* and they need to be split into 100 fields... Luckily PyQGIS can do it :)

Comment: @Taras: luckily, QGIS can import Excel spreadsheets too :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use QGIS expressions to convert your string to an array containing each number as an element with `string_to_array`. You now can use `array_get ([your_array],[index])` to return every element. Index starts with 0.

So the whole expression to get the third value (index=2) looks like ("column" is the name of the input field):

`array_get (string_to_array ("column",'-'), 2)`

For an input field containing `143-685-6749`, the expression returns `6749`. If you change the value of `2` at the end by `1`, it returns `685`, setting it to `0` returns `143`.

[image]

Comment: what if we want to split data from the end. If we dont know the number of elements in the cell.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe function array_length() is what you need

Comment: what i mean is in above example we know that there are four elements or five elements. But in my dataset their are multiple elements seperated by - . I want to split the last element how can i proceed

Comment: Depends very much an the very use case. Provide detailed information how exactly your data structure looks like and what output you expect. Best post a new question and be as precise as possible. To just get the last element of the array, use array_last().

Answer (score 5):

In case a PyQGIS approach is needed:

```
def text_to_columns(text_column_name, new_columns_name, delimiter): 
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()

    splits = [feat[text_column_name].split(delimiter) for feat in layer.getFeatures() if feat[text_column_name] != NULL]
    max_split_length = len(max(splits, key=len))
    new_fields = []

    for i in range(1,max_split_length+1): 
        field_name = f'{new_columns_name}_{i}'
        new_field = QgsField(field_name, QVariant.String)
        if layer.fields().lookupField(field_name) == -1:
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([new_field])
            layer.updateFields()
        new_fields.append(field_name)

    for i, feat in enumerate(layer.getFeatures()): 
        if feat[text_column_name] == NULL: continue
        feat_text_parts = splits[i]
        for text_part, field in zip(feat_text_parts, new_fields): 
            feat[field] = text_part
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
    layer.commitChanges()

text_to_columns('COLUMN', 'NEW_COL', '-')
```

This will create the the fields depending on what the biggest array is after splitting the texts.
The Script will create something like this: [image]

Comment: Nice but can be more optimized : the `for feat in layer.getFeatures() [...] feat[text_column_name].split(delimiter)` is done twice, a `new_columns_name+'_'+i` is more pythonic like that `f"{new_columns_name}_{i}"` and will add the `layer` as function argument.

Comment: I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: I have edited my answer. The error occurs when you have a NULL value because NULL is a type of QVariant. You may need to import NULL from qgis.core when using the script from outside the qgis python console.